# .Net Monodroid spinner auto-fill

Tags: forms, spinner, xamarin.android

I am using .Net and Monodroid to develop Android applications, however I seem to have hit a wall when it comes to filling in a Spinner at run time, as I do not have access to the [Spinner Object].SetAdapter(...) method. I have been to both

developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-spinner.html
and 
android.xamarin.com/Tutorials
as well as
stackoverflow.com/questions/3958866/how-to-change-the-contents-of-spinner-on-run-time-in-android

and everything relies on this method. Is this a limitation of the unregistered version? Because they do not say anything about feature-limits here android.xamarin.com/DownloadTrial

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Mono for Android, many cases where Java will have getXXXX/setXXXX methods get translated into properties named XXXX, in order to be more .NET friendly. In this case, Spinner.setAdapter() in Java becomes [Spinner.Adapter](http://docs.mono-android.net/index.aspx?link=P%3aAndroid.Widget.AbsSpinner.Adapter) in Mono for Android:

```
Spinner spinner = FindViewById<Spinner> (Resource.Id.spinner);  
spinner.Adapter = new ArrayAdapter...
```

Xamarin also has a Spinner tutorial available [here](http://android.xamarin.com/Tutorials/Hello_Views/Spinner) that might help you get going.

Comment: Thanks - is there anyway to allow the user to continually add items and refresh the spinner control?

Comment: You can call NotifyDataSetChanged() on the adapter to tell it that the  underlying data has been modified.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it - there is an Adapter **property** that can be used to access the Adapter.

Also it turns out you must check if the adapter is null first - you cannot read a null object :)

if (_itemlist.Adapter == null)
{
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleSpinnerItem, items);
}

the only problem is that it does not automatically refresh and the invalidate(...) method does not cause it to redraw with the new items...